# Determine if a function is the null function from conditions on integral

Tags: integration, continuity

I want to find out if the following statement is true and if it is to prove it:

for $f : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous and integrable, if $\int_a^b f(x) dx = 0$ and $\int_a^b x f(x) dx = 0$ then $f(x) = 0, \forall x\in[a,b]$

in order to generalize it to two variables

if $\int_\Omega f(x,y) dxdy = 0$, $\int_\Omega x f(x,y) dxdy=0$ and $\int_\Omega yf(x,y) dxdy =0$ then $f(x,y)=0, \forall (x,y)\in\Omega$ where $\Omega$
is some domain of $\mathbb R^2$.

I tried to prove it using mean theorems but cannot lead to anything. I cannot think about a counter-example as well.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous and integrable or just integrable?

Comment: $f$ is continuous in my case.

Comment: How about $x-\frac 53 x^3$ from $[-1,1]$?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a good counter-example, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To produce counterexamples, take an interval symmetric about $0$, $[-1,1]$, say.  Now let $g(x),h(x)$ be odd functions.  Then we certainly get $$\int_{-1}^1 \left(g(x)-C\,h(x)\right)dx=0\;\;\forall C\in \mathbb R$$

Now just set the constant $C$ in in such a way to make $$\int_{-1}^1 x\left(g(x)-C\,h(x)\right)dx=0$$

As a concrete example, with $g(x)=x,h(x)=x^3$ a short calculation shows that we can take $$f(x)=x-\frac 53x^3$$